# while and for loop to infinite in java

Tags: java

i have a exercice to do in Java. I need to create a World Cup tournament and the restriction is that the program will restart until my favourite team win. However, if my team didn't win after 20 times, the program stop

The problem is when I try to put the second restriction (20 times max) with a for after the *while (true)*,  I always get an infinite loop.

```
//Q1

String[] teams16 = {"Uruguay", "Portugal", "France", "Argentina", "Brazil", "Mexico", 
    "Belgium", "Japan", "Spain", "Russia", "Croatia", "Denmark", "Sweden", "Switzerland", 
    "Colombia", "England"};


//data
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
Random result = new Random();
System.out.print("Enter your favourite team: ");
String team = keyboard.nextLine();
boolean teamwc = false;

// choice of the favourite team
for (int i = 0 ; i < 16 ; i++ ) {
    if (teams16[i].equalsIgnoreCase(team)) {
        teamwc = true;      
    }
}
if(teamwc == false) {
    System.out.println("Your team is not in the Round of 16 ");
}


// the tournament begins (ROUND OF 16)
while (true) {
    if (teamwc == true) {
        int z = 0;
        String[] winnerof16 = new String[8];
        int a = 0;

        System.out.print("ROUND OF 16:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 16 ; i+=2) {
            int score1 = result.nextInt(5);
            int score2 = result.nextInt(5);

            if (score1 > score2) {
                winnerof16 [a] = teams16[i];
            }
            else if (score1 < score2) {
                winnerof16[a] = teams16[i+1];

            } else if (score1 == score2) {
                Random overtime = new Random();
                int ot = overtime.nextInt(2);
                    if (ot == 0) {
                        score1++;
                        winnerof16[a] = teams16[i];
                    } else if (ot == 1) {
                        score2++;
                        winnerof16[a]=teams16[i+1];
                    }
                }
                System.out.print("["+teams16[i] +"]"+ " " + score1+":"+score2 + " " + "["+teams16[i+1]+"]" + " ");
                a++;    
            }
            System.out.println();
            String[] winnerof8 = new String[4];
            int b = 0;
            System.out.print("QUARTER-FINALS:");
            for (int k = 0 ; k < 8 ; k+=2) { 
                int score3 = result.nextInt(5);
                int score4 = result.nextInt(5);
                if (score3 > score4) {
                    winnerof8[b]=winnerof16[k];
                }
                else if (score3 < score4) {
                    winnerof8[b] = winnerof16[k+1];                 
                } else if (score3 == score4) {
                    Random overtime2 = new Random();
                    int ot2 = overtime2.nextInt(2);
                    if (ot2 == 0) {
                        score3++;
                        winnerof8[b]=winnerof16[k];
                    } else if (ot2 == 1) {
                        score4++;
                        winnerof8[b]=winnerof16[k+1];
                    }                   
                }
                System.out.print("["+winnerof16[k] +"]"+ " " + score3+":"+score4 + " " + "["+winnerof16[k+1]+"]" + " ");
                b++;
            }
            System.out.println();
            String[] winnerof4 = new String[2];
            int c = 0;
            System.out.print("SEMI-FINALS:");
            for (int l = 0 ; l < 4 ; l+=2) { 
                int score5 = result.nextInt(5);
                int score6 = result.nextInt(5);
                if (score5 > score6) {
                    winnerof4[c]=winnerof8[l];
                }
                else if (score5 < score6) {
                    winnerof4[c] = winnerof8[l+1];                  
                } else if (score5 == score6) {
                    Random overtime3 = new Random();
                    int ot3 = overtime3.nextInt(2);
                    if (ot3 == 0) {
                        score5++;
                        winnerof4[c]=winnerof8[l];
                    } else if (ot3 == 1) {
                        score6++;
                        winnerof4[c]=winnerof8[l+1];
                    }                   
                }
                System.out.print("["+winnerof8[l] +"]"+ " " + score5+":"+score6 + " " + "["+winnerof8[l+1]+"]" + " ");
                    c++;
                }
                System.out.println();
                String[] winnerof2 = new String[1];
                int d = 0;
                System.out.print("FINALS:");
                for (int m = 0 ; m < 2 ; m+=2) { 
                    int score7 = result.nextInt(5);
                    int score8 = result.nextInt(5);
                    if (score7 > score8) {
                        winnerof2[d]=winnerof4[m];
                    }
                    else if (score7 < score8) {
                        winnerof2[d] = winnerof4[m+1];                      
                    } else if (score7 == score8) {
                        Random overtime4 = new Random();
                        int ot4 = overtime4.nextInt(2);
                        if (ot4 == 0) {
                            score7++;
                            winnerof2[d]=winnerof4[m];
                        } else if (ot4 == 1) {
                            score8++;
                            winnerof2[d]=winnerof4[m+1];
                        }

                    }
                    System.out.print("["+winnerof4[m] +"]"+ " " + score7+":"+score8 + " " + "["+winnerof4[m+1]+"]" + " ");
                    System.out.println();
                }


                System.out.println("Tournament: " + z +  " The WINNER is: " + winnerof2[d]);
                z++;
                if (winnerof2[d].equalsIgnoreCase(team)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code before I put the second restriction.
Is there a problem with my code ? How can I put the second restriction ? Thank you

Comment: Hi, you should edit your question’s title as it is too broad. First, this is homework, second you did not provide any input nor outputs of your program. Third, you probably are developing using eclipse: there are tools for debug and step by step execution, breakpoint etc. You’ll find plenty of documentation on google to help you use it.

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop is due to this 2:

```
while (true) { // it will quit while loop only when an exception raised
if (teamwc == true) { // after this you nowhere assign teamwc == false therefore it is always true
```

instead of direct assigning `True` to while loop, use a boolean variable or a condition to quit somewhere:

```
t = true
while(t):
```

OR

```
while n>0:
```